# Format Date fields in Pipe Delimited File

Tags: text-processing, awk

I require assistance with this I have a pipe delimited file that is formatted as such

```
Location|1111|222222|333333|Doe|John|19900723|19900724|19900725
```

The last 3 fields are Date fields, but I can't seem to format them as such.  I need them formatted as **1990/07/23**.  I'm learning awk so I'd prefer to do it through awk, but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kusalananda comments, you can just do some string manipulation:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '
    function format_date(d) { return substr(d,1,4) "/" substr(d,5,2) "/" substr(d,7) }
    { for (i = 7; i <= 9; i++) $i = format_date($i); print }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN {OFS="|"} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,strftime("%Y/%m/%d",$7),strftime("%Y/%m/%d",$8),strftime("%Y/%m/%d",$9)}' inputfile
```

The key here is `strftime()`, which will format the date provided in the second parameter using the format string in the first parameter:

```
$ echo "1552924174" | awk '{print strftime("%Y/%m/%d", $1) }'
2019/03/18
```

`strftime()` is supported by GNU `awk` and by `mawk`, but not by BSD `awk`.

Comment: Alternatively, update the relevant fields and just `print`.

Comment: `strftime` is great if you have a `time_t` value, i.e. seconds since 1970 (given Unix), not the values this OP has which are yyyymmdd treated as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `Perl` as shewn:

**Input:**

```
$ cat file
Location|1111|222222|333333|Doe|John|19900723|19900724|19900725

$ perl -lpe 's#\|\K([0-9]{8})(?=(?:(?:\|[0-9]{8}){0,2})$)#join "/", unpack "A4A2A2", $1#ge' file
Location|1111|222222|333333|Doe|John|1990/07/23|1990/07/24|1990/07/25
```

**Explanation:**

- `-l` sets RS = ORS = "\n"
- `-p` reads input file in records with the record separator set above. Also, prints the current record to stdout before reading in the next one.
- `-e` applies the `Perl` code that follows this option to every record (`$_`) read in.
- The `regex` finds out 8-digit numbers those that are preceded by a pipe and followed by at the most two neighbors of the same variety as itself before it sees the end of line. They are stored captured in `$1`.
- Now each captured `$1` is unpacked according to the `A4A2A2` pattern and these patterns are then joined together with a slash.

**Alternate:**

```
$ perl -F'[|]' -pale '$_ = join "/", unpack "A4A2A2" for @F[-3..-1]; $_ = join "|", @F'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method

```
`echo "Location|1111|222222|333333|Doe|John|19900723|19900724|19900725"| awk -F "|" '{$NF=substr($NF,1,4)"/"substr($NF,5,2)"/"substr($NF,7,2);$(NF-1)=substr($(NF-1),1,4)"/"substr($(NF-1),5,2)"/"substr($(NF-1),7,2);$(NF-2)=substr($(NF-2),1,4)"/"substr($(NF-2),5,2)"/"substr($(NF-2),7,2);print $0}'| sed "s/ /`|/g"
```

output

```
echo "Location|1111|222222|333333|Doe|John|19900723|19900724|19900725"| awk -F "|" '{$NF=substr($NF,1,4)"/"substr($NF,5,2)"/"substr($NF,7,2);$(NF-1)=substr($(NF-1),1,4)"/"substr($(NF-1),5,2)"/"substr($(NF-1),7,2);$(NF-2)=substr($(NF-2),1,4)"/"substr($(NF-2),5,2)"/"substr($(NF-2),7,2);print $0}'| sed "s/ /|/g"


Location|1111|222222|333333|Doe|John|1990/07/23|1990/07/24|1990/07/25
```

Comment: Rather than using `sed` to change all spaces in the output of `awk` into pipes, you could simply set `OFS="|" ` in the `awk` code. That way you don't run the risk of accidentally creating _new_ fields due to spaces in the input data.